# how to design an API for mobile that accepts only 100K requests within an Hour span

Tags: api, system-design

how to design an API for mobile that accepts only 100K requests within an Hour span. If the number of requests are more than 100K in less than 1 hour, we have to reject the request. What all aspects we need to consider to design such API. We do not need to store the user request. Our API has to just either accept or reject the request, that means it has to send true or false as response. If we are accepting the request we have to send true else false.

Answer (score 0):

For designing any such api where request per hour needs to be tracked, my opinion is to have a counter of requests coming starting from 100 and keep on reducing it by one for each coming request. Also save the start time for first request received and the time when new request is received if time gap is less than 60 mins and request count is greater than 0 allow the request. In case time gap is less than 60 mins and count is equal to 0 reject the request and if time gap is greater than 60 reset both the time and counter.